# How to prevent this window behaviour in Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, openbox, visual-artifacts, screen-tearing

This happens when I move the windows. Details:

- openbox
- ATI proprietary driver
- no problem in OpenGL contexts
- I don't want to use any compositing manager

[image: The issue!]

It's not so strange, quite common in fact. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing).

---

> Obviously this image doesn't reproduce a *real* screen tearing. I found that the Gimp screen capture gave a good idea of what happens, so I tried this way to explain the issue.

Comment: "Problem with ATI proprietary driver" becomes "Complain to ATI".

Comment: Not too sure, it's just a lack of vertical synchronization.

Comment: Looks cool, just keep it this way. Just kidding... :)

Comment: @Sergiy Byelozyorov: Kinda Picasso, uh?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Catalyst 11.1 appears the **Tear Free Desktop** option; that solves the issue.

1. Display Options
2. Tear Free
3. Enable Tear Free Desktop to reduce tearing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to avoid this by using outline dragging instead of showing the full contents.

In Windows 7 you will find it under Control Panel/System/Advanced System Settings/

Scroll down and uncheck "Show windows content while dragging"

It might be a problem with your driver or a product of your system specifications.

I found my netbook works much better with outline dragging turned on.

Comment: Windows 7? What?

Comment: I'm using Debian Squeeze and I don't want to set such option.

Answer (score 0):

Check your compiz modules; there are some "visual effects" which let your windows "wobble" when you drag them. Maybe you activated one of them.

[EDIT] Screen tearing can't be captured in a screenshot since it's an optical effect that happens only on the monitor (not in RAM). Also the effect above is too regular and has too many tear lines; with normal screen tearing, you have only a single tear (or maybe two if you move the window really fast).

Therefore, the effect must be created by some program.

**[EDIT2]** Again: The image above is a screenshot. That means some software on your computer creates the effect. Reason: No software in the world is able to capture the optical illusion of screen tearing which happens when two refreshes on the monitor happen while something changes. So you must look at all the programs running, check the config of your window manager, find the culprit and shut it off.

Comment: I don't use (and I don't want to) compiz. It's not a decoration effect . Read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing.

Comment: The image above: Is that a screenshot done with a program or a mockup to visualize the effect?

Comment: Just Gimp screen capture.

Comment: Then it's not screen tearing. Screen tearing would give you a **single** horizontal tear while you move the window. This can't be captured by gimp. The effect above is created by some program (-> too regular, can be captured, too much tearing).

Comment: THIS IS CAPTURED BY GIMP. Obviously this image doesn't reproduce a *real* screen tearing. I found that the Gimp screen capture gave a good idea of what happens, so I tried this way to explain the issue. The fact is that I (still) have a problem of screen tearing that you haven't solved with your wise response.

Comment: It's a bit hard to debug an issue if you don't provide meaningful information :-) I don't care if you captured the image with GIMP. I need to know: Did you **edit** that image in any way after capturing? Can GIMP **see** the screen tearing or did you add the effect afterwards?

Comment: I did not edit the image after the capture. Let's try this way: ignore this picture ok?; I have a screen tearing problem in a normal window management context that I can't solve (see details in the question). Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. Look for the program which creates the effect because it's not the purely visual screen tearing because no program in the world could capture that. To get the image above, some software must render it into the memory of your gfx card. Find that software and shut it down.

Comment: I give up with you...